Murder in eight different perspectives
I am looking for a movie which depicts a murder in eight different perspectives. I think it's a whodunit plot movie I saw the ad once on TV where they show something like a influential person like president is about to conspired and killed and they show 8 other characters trying to depict that information as to reveal the identity of the killer.

Kurosawa's Rashomon has the many views on one murder element (first time in film I think), but takes place in feudal Japan so the President is not involved.

One sub-genre of the whodunit is the film noir movie with a twist ending at the end. One excellent film of that genre is The Usual Suspects. I think you'll quite like that film. Oh, and I also enjoyed Clue alot, but was quite happy to see it on video where all three endings are shown, instead of having to run to three different showings when the movie came out.

Another film fitting the gengre is Mindhunters(or at least I think it fits the pattern...).

@Dragos will check it out. Thanks

@BarryHammer How would i ever miss Usual suspects. I should've added that to my list.

Vantage Point (2008) : attempted assassination of the American President is told and re-told from several different perspectives
